# Dynamically added inputs groups validation problem

Tags: jquery

Can't validate dynamically added inputs groups.
I used jquery-validate: v1.19.2 (https://jqueryvalidation.org/) on Chrome 84.0.4147.89
Steps to reproduce:
https://jsfiddle.net/7hzv8fgn/
I append this block:

```
<div class="product-form-template">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center font-weight-bold"><h4 class="count-input">#1:</h4></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Product_name[]" placeholder="Product name*" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Size[]" placeholder="Size">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Color[]" placeholder="Color">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Qty[]" placeholder="Qty*" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Price[]" placeholder="Price*" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Validate only first block of inputs. How to validate all of them?

Comment: You Must call *.validate(...) After the append of the new items to the Dom.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work either. I added v.form() to begin of updateNumbers function